# Не работает функция mail_admins в Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, views

Пишу учебный проект на Django. В нем есть есть функции отправки письма на почту пользователя (так как сервер доступен только на локальной машине, то письма выводятся в консоль). Когда использую функцию `mail_admins`, то в консоль почему-то ничего не выводится. Однако при использовании функции `send_mail` все работает прекрасно.

Вот код класса-представления, который отправляет письмо:

```py
class FeedBackView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/feedback_form.html'
    form_class = FeedBackForm
    success_url = '/'
    extra_context = {'form': FeedBackForm()}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = render_to_string(
            "main/email_to_admin_template.html",
            {
                'user_email': request.user.email,
                'message_text': request.POST.get('text')
            },
        )
        mail_admins(subject='Обратная связь', message=message, fail_silently=False)
        return super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

HTML-шаблон самого письма:

```
{% autoescape off %}

Пользователь с почтой {{ user_email }} отправил вам сообщение:
{{ message_text }}

{% endautoescape %}
```

Настройка `EMAIL_BACKEND`:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Логичный вопрос — эти самые ADMINS вообще прописаны в настройках?

Comment: Нет, не знал про это, после вашего комментария в доку полез и разобрался, спасибо